# Organizing data to access information based on either variable depending on what is required

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, graph-algorithm

I am given a list of elements with their respective lists of nodes, and I want to switch how I look them up. I'd like to have a list of nodes with lists of their respective elements.

Example:

```
Have
E    N
1    1 2 3
2    2 3 4
3    1 4

Desired
N    E
1    1 3
2    1 2
3    1 2
4    2 3
```

I have a nested for loop solution.

```py
# known data
elements = [
    [],  # No element 0
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [1, 4],
]

max_element = 3
max_node = 4

# truth
truth_nodes = [
    [],
    [1, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
]

# current algorithm
nodes = [[] for n in range(max_node+1)]

for node in range(1, max_node + 1):
    for element in range(1, max_element + 1):
        if node in elements[element]:
                nodes[node].append(element)
```

Is there another tool in Python, either with NumPy, Pandas, or something else that might speed this up for over 300,000 elements? If this is a common algorithm, what is its name and/or how would I find it?

Edit: Is this a graph algorithm?

I can imagine vertices for my nodes above as well as my elements and using NetworkX to make an undirected graph. Then would I use a connected component algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a pandas DataFrame with columns `node` and `element` and a row for every pair of a single node belonging to a single element.

```
Node Element
1    1
2    1
3    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
1    3
4    3
```

I believe this follows [Tidy Data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) by Hadley Wickham. Then I could call a given `node` by a boolean index `df[df.node==1]`, and likewise for an element, `df[df.element==3]`.

I am still not sure if this is a graph algorithm, but organizing my data this way allowed me to move forward with the rest of the problem.